# change array name in array with array_push function

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
 $array = array ('item' =>array("title" => "Revolution","size" => "100", "link" => "www"));
 $add = array("title" => "Revolution","size" => "100", "link" => "www");
 array_push($array, $add);
 print_r ($array);
```

and result is this:

```
Array
(
[item] => Array
    (
        [title] => Revolution
        [size] => 100
        [link] => www
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Revolution
        [size] => 100
        [link] => www
    )

)
```

How to change the [0] to [item:1], i'm lost.

Thanks 
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `array_push` use this syntax:

```
$array['item:1'] = array("title" => "Revolution","size" => "100", "link" => "www");
```

This way you can specify the key name you want, whereas `array_push` just increments the numeric index.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
array_push($array, $add);
```

write

```
$array['item:1'] = $add;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean $array["items"][1]. Push to `$array["items"]` instead.

Alternatively, just do `$array["items"][] = arraystuff`, and it will handle the numbering for you.